# How to get multi select data and add check box in each item of the list using Angular.js?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need to add check box in each item and get the multi selected value using Angular.js. My code is below.

```
<body ng-controller="speshController">
  <h1>Hello</h1>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="input-group bmargindiv1 col-md-12">
      <span class="input-group-addon ndrftextwidth text-right" style="width:180px">Child Business Name :</span>
      <select class="form-control" multiple="multiple" id="restau" ng-model="restaurant" ng-options="qua.name for qua in listOfRestaurant  track by qua.value" ng-change="getDayFromSpecial('restau');">
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button type="button" id="btn" ng-click="getValue();">GET</button>
</body>
```

Here I have one drop down list and I need to add check box before each item from drop down list. Suppose user selected multiple item while it will clicked on `GET` button I need to fetch those selected data. My controller side code is given below.

```
app.controller('speshController',function($scope,$http){
  $scope.data=[{
    'value':1,
    'name':'aaa'
  },{
    'value':2,
    'name':'bvc'
  },{
    'value':3,
    'name':'rtcv'
  },{
    'value':4,
    'name':'uytg'
  }
  ]
  $scope.listOfRestaurant=[];
  angular.forEach($scope.data,function(obj){
    var data={'name':obj.name,'value':obj.value};
        $scope.listOfRestaurant.push(data);
  })
  $scope.getValue=function(){

  }

})
```

I need to displayed those selected data in console. My [full code is here](https://plnkr.co/edit/7jsm4GJq7qSkG06q4KRK?p=preview).

Comment: you already Have the ng-model use that https://plnkr.co/edit/cqwbxRnQQAVrSm55nI6P?p=preview

Comment: @satya, Did you find solution?

Answer (score 0):

ng-model on multi-select will give you the selected items as array

```
 $scope.getValue=function(){
   console.log($scope.restaurant) 
 }
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/cqwbxRnQQAVrSm55nI6P?p=preview

Comment: Its coming but i need to add check box format also.

Comment: I have updated the plunker again, Please have a look, are you looking for something like multi-checkbox ?

Comment: No,inside that drop down item,i need check box before the item not outside again.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, it is better to use checkbox with labels instead of multiselect dropdown.

```
<label ng-repeat="qua in listOfRestaurant track by qua.value">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="qua.selected"/>
    {{qua.name}}
</label>
```

You can test in [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/2KkgEv6g0SJomOk0mlLH?p=preview).